# Async ICommand delegate for MVVM Pattern with return value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, lambda

I just started programming in C# and wanted to do anything right from start.
So i learned about MVVM Pattern and tried to make my program work with it.
For that i used a Delegate from ICommand with lambda functions.

This works fine, but since my program uses HTML requests I had to find a way to make the calls to the Commands async.

So i found a nice implementation which i tried to understand but I failed at one point... Here comes the Implementation:

```
    public interface IRaiseCanExecuteChanged
    {
        void RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    // And an extension method to make it easy to raise changed events
    public static class CommandExtensions
    {
        public static void RaiseCanExecuteChanged(this ICommand command)
        {
            var canExecuteChanged = command as IRaiseCanExecuteChanged;

            if (canExecuteChanged != null)
                canExecuteChanged.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public class DelegateCommand : DelegateCommand<object>
    {
        public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod)
            : base(o => executeMethod())
        {
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
            : base(o => executeMethod(), o => canExecuteMethod())
        {
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A command that calls the specified delegate when the command is executed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand, IRaiseCanExecuteChanged
    {
        private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecuteMethod;
        private readonly Action<T> _executeMethod;
        private bool _isExecuting;

        public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod)
            : this(executeMethod, null)
        {
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
        {
            if ((executeMethod == null) && (canExecuteMethod == null))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("executeMethod", @"Execute Method cannot be null");
            }
            _executeMethod = executeMethod;
            _canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }

        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return !_isExecuting && CanExecute((T)parameter);
        }

        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _isExecuting = true;
            try
            {
                RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                Execute((T)parameter);
            }
            finally
            {
                _isExecuting = false;
                RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(T parameter)
        {
            if (_canExecuteMethod == null)
                return true;

            return _canExecuteMethod(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(T parameter)
        {
            _executeMethod(parameter);
        }
    }

    public interface IAsyncCommand : IAsyncCommand<object>
    {
    }

    public interface IAsyncCommand<in T> : IRaiseCanExecuteChanged
    {
        Task ExecuteAsync(T obj);
        bool CanExecute(object obj);
        ICommand Command { get; }
    }

    public class AwaitableDelegateCommand : AwaitableDelegateCommand<object>, IAsyncCommand
    {
        public AwaitableDelegateCommand(Func<Task> executeMethod)
            : base(o => executeMethod())
        {
        }

        public AwaitableDelegateCommand(Func<Task> executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
            : base(o => executeMethod(), o => canExecuteMethod())
        {
        }
    }

    public class AwaitableDelegateCommand<T> : IAsyncCommand<T>, ICommand
    {
        private readonly Func<T, Task> _executeMethod;
        private readonly DelegateCommand<T> _underlyingCommand;
        private bool _isExecuting;

        public AwaitableDelegateCommand(Func<T, Task> executeMethod)
            : this(executeMethod, _ => true)
        {
        }

        public AwaitableDelegateCommand(Func<T, Task> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
        {
            _executeMethod = executeMethod;
            _underlyingCommand = new DelegateCommand<T>(x => { }, canExecuteMethod);
        }

        public async Task ExecuteAsync(T obj)
        {
            try
            {
                _isExecuting = true;
                RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                await _executeMethod(obj);
            }
            finally
            {
                _isExecuting = false;
                RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand Command { get { return this; } }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return !_isExecuting && _underlyingCommand.CanExecute((T)parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { _underlyingCommand.CanExecuteChanged += value; }
            remove { _underlyingCommand.CanExecuteChanged -= value; }
        }

        public async void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            await ExecuteAsync((T)parameter);
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            _underlyingCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now I've got two questions. 
1. Is it a good one to implement it like they did? As I can see the object T is just used as function parameter which I can pass to my lambda function.

What I can do with this code is the following:

```
    private ObservableList<string, string> dict;
    private IAsyncCommand searchCommand;
    public async Task myFunction() {
        //changes global variable dict bound to view
    public IAsyncCommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (myCommand == null)
            {
                myCommand = new AwaitableDelegateCommand(
                    () =>
                    {
                        return myFunction(myParameter);
                    });
            }
        return searchCommand;
        }
    }
```

where myFunction edits a global variable dict which is bound to the view via function MyFunction with getters and setters. I hope this is the common practice because I just found it like that.
We return the task here and the AwaitableDelegateCommand internally waits for it so we don't have to care about. But we can't access the task nor its result, right?

So how could I achieve this if myFunction does not return void but a variable.
Then I would have to get the Result of the Task (after waiting async) and assign it to list.

Code would look like this:

```
    public async Task<ObservableDictionary<string, string>> myFunction() {
        var dict = new ObservableDictionary<string, string>();
        //do work....
        return dict;
    }
    public IAsyncCommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (myCommand == null)
            {
                //what to do here to assign dict the result of the Task?
            }
        return searchCommand;
        }
    }
```

That would make my code more reusable and I want it to be good :)
Hope someone can help me.

EDIT:
Since my problem does not seem to be very clear I try to explain it again.

My method returns a value and I want my method to run async with the AwaitableDelegateCommand

Now the problem... A method which returns a value usually do nothing with the rest of the code, but with the value that is returned...
In my case it populates a dictionary from a HTML request and returns it.
If I now run the method async in the lambda, it does nothing.... because I can't get the result of the Task in background. 
So I solved this now by rewriting the function. Instead of populating a local dictionary variable, it populates a global one.
That's the only way I could figure out to have access to the data of the function.
I just want to know if there is another way to do this or if this is the only/best way.

Hope this is better.

Answer (score 1):

The `ICommand` bindings in wpf are fire-and-forget, that is, they do not have a direct return value. The effect of a command returns from the view model through the use of `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
internal class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyViewModel( IServer server )
    {
        MyCommand = new DelegateCommand( async () => MyProperty = await server.GetNewData() );
    }

    #region Bindings
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _myProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand { get; }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region private
    private string _myProperty;

    private void OnPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null )
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }
    #endregion
}

public interface IServer
{
    Task<string> GetNewData();
}
```

and `MyView` will have something like this:

```
<Button Content="Click me!" Command={Binding MyCommand}" />
<TextBlock Text={Binding MyProperty} />
```

Now, if you click the button, the `MyCommand` is executed, requests data from the server and updates `MyProperty` once the data arrives. `MyProperty` triggers an update to `MyView`'s `TextBlock` and the user sees the new data...

EDIT:

> In my case [the method] populates a dictionary from a HTML request and returns it.

And because of that, the method is inept to be used (directly) as delegate in a command.  A delegate called by a command has to *modify the state of the application*, otherwise the command does nothing, as you correctly stated. So you should create a command with a delegate that calls the method and does something with the return value:

```
MyCommand = new DelegateCommand( async () => _model.Add( await ParseDataFromRequest() );
```

That being said, `ParseDataFromRequest` shouldn't be a member of the view model anyway, it belongs to the logic-part of the application. The view model should just forward and adapt data for consumation by the view.

Comment: sorry pressed enter and couldn't edit in time -.-"
I didn't use OnPropertyChanged thing til now. That's really useful if my dictionary get's new data ;) 
But my question was if I can get Functions with return value working with Commands (i.e. make it behave like a task?) 
I mean the implementation is completely overworked :P maybe I can change some code to make that work? Or is it completely not possible?
I just don't want my function to edit global variable to make it reusable for other programs.

Comment: Why should you not be able to use functions with return values in a command? Just discard the return value... `new Command( () => ThisMethodReturnsSomething() )`

Comment: But I need the return value to assign it to my global variable. I just want to make it reusable. If I use the function without returning, it does nothing because what I return is also the thing I created/edited. I don't want to have my method changed just for using it as a command.

Comment: Despite using global variables being evil, you can write `new Command( () => _globalVariable = ThisMethodWantsToModifyTheModel() )`

Comment: My method is async and returns a task. So i could just get the task. But I want to do it in background in my async delegate.
Besides that my question was how to get a return value.... If that could be answered I don't have to use global variables:P

Comment: Can you clearify the question? I don't get it :-) For a method, you get the return value by calling the method, and you won't get a return value from a command _at all_ because commands don't have return values.

Comment: I edited my first post. Hope it's more clear now... otherwise I made a "minimal" example but it would make the post longer xD

Comment: btw what do you mean with "Despite using global variables being evil"? How do you store data for a list?

Comment: you don't want to use global variables, because they create strong coupling and prevent you from mocking stuff in tests.

Comment: But how can you store Data then?... I mean e.g. data to be shown on a listbox has to be stored as a global Variable or not?
I understand it like you can just bind properties to view in mvvm.
So any property has a global Variable behind, hmm?

Comment: The data source for a listbox on a view should be stored as a property on the viewmodel of the view.

Comment: Are you confusing _global variable_ with _field_? global is a special kind of field like `public static int IAmGlobal;` and a normal, private _field_ is `private int _index;`

Comment: hmm i don't think that the property of variables being global is bound to keyworkd static... i thought of like you said private variables because they are kind of 'global' to the class and not gone if, e.g. method is done (that would be local in the method). Kind of confusing I think...
I think you didn't got my problem yet :S don't know how i can explain it better....  I will try to give an minimal example and edit my post then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asynchronously retrieving data, I recommend using something like `NotifyTask<T>` in my [`Mvvm.Async` library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async). It's based off an old article I wrote about [async data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

E.g., given:

```
public async Task<Result> MyFunctionAsync();
```

You could have your ViewModel look something like:

```
public NotifyTask<Result> MyFunctionResults { get { ... } private set { ... /* raise PropertyChanged */ } }
public ICommand StartMyFunction { get; } = new DelegateCommand(() =>
{
  MyFunctionResults = NotifyTask.Create(MyFunctionAsync());
});
```

And then your data binding would use `MyFunctionResults.Result` to show the result. The data binding can also use `MyFunctionResults.IsNotCompleted` and other utility properties to show/hide spinners and error indicators.

Note that an asynchronous command is not necessary here. The command only *starts* the asynchronous operation, and the async data binding is used to update the UI when the data arrives.